# First order linear function mixture problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Assuming the mixture is uniform

A $400$ gallon tank initially contains $100$ gallons of brine containing $50$lbs of salt. Brine containing 1 lb\gallon enters the tank at a rate of $5$ gal/sec. The well-mixed brine in the tank flows out at a rate of $3$ gal/seconds. How much salt will the tank contain when it is full of brine?

according to: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Modeling.aspx

The formula we want is: the overall rate of change is equal to rate the fluid enters the tank minus the rate at which the fluid leaves the tank. The rate at which the fluid enters or leaves is equal to the flow rate times the concentration. Concentration is equal to amount of salt divided by the amount of water.

Setting the equation up:

Concentration entering the tank: $1$ lb/gal

rate it enters the tank: $5$ gal/seconds

rate it leaves the tank: $3$ gal/seconds

volume of water at any time $t$: $100g + 2g \times t$

$Q(t):$ The amount of salt at any time t.

initial conditions: at $t=0$ the concentration = $.5 lb/gal$

Important to note that since $5$gal/sec enters the tank and $3$gal/sec leaves the tank the volume increases by $2$gal/sec which is taken into consideration above.

Setting up the equation:

Q'(t)= overall rate of change

$Q'(t)=(1 lb/gal)(5gal/sec)-(\frac{Q(t)?}{100gal + 2gal(t)})$($3$gal/sec)$

I guess I take the integral now

simplifying

$Q'(t)=  5lb/sec - \frac{?}{100+2gal(t)}(3gal/sec)$

$Q'(t) -\frac{3gal/secQ(t)}{100+2gt}= 5 $lb/sec

integrating factor $u(x)= e^{\int \frac{3gal/sec}{100+2gt}}$

$u(x)= (50+t)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

$\frac{1}{(50+t)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \int 5 (50+t)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

the fives cancel out and of course this gives:

$\frac{1}{50+t^{\frac{3}{2}}} \times 2(50+t)^{\frac{5}{2}}+c$

after multiplying through we get:

$2(50+t)+ \frac{c}{50+t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

applying the initial condition:

Q(0)=50:

$50 = 100+\frac{c}{\sqrt{(50)^3}}$

$-50= \frac{c}{\sqrt{(50)^3}}$

$c = (-50)(\sqrt{(50)^3}$

Now $Q(t) = 100 + 2t + \frac{c}{(50+t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}=100+2t-\frac{50^{5/2}}{(50+t)^{3/2}}$

The problem doesn't offer a time when the tank is done getting filled the book says it 397 approx. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you call the quantity of salt as $Q(t)\rm{lb}$, and the time $t\rm{sec}$, and don't mix $\rm g$ and $\rm{gal}$ in your equations. It will make for cleaner expressions. Then you have $$Q'(t)\rm{lb/sec}=5\rm{lb/sec}-\frac{Q(t)\rm{lb}}{100\rm{gal}+2\rm{gal/sec}\ t\rm{sec}}3\rm{gal/sec}$$
The units look right, so the equation in dimensionless quantities is now:
$$Q'(t)=5-\frac{3Q(t)}{100+2t}$$
Move the $Q$ term to the other side and you get 
$$Q'(t)+\frac{3Q(t)}{100+2t}=5$$
Now the integrating function is $$\mu(t)=e^{\int \frac{3}{100+2t}dt}=e^{\frac32\int \frac{1}{50+t}dt}=(50+t)^{3/2}$$
Just in case you need it, $\int(50+t)^{3/2}=\frac25(50+t)^{5/2}$

Comment: Do where do I proceed from here? I'm not 100 percent sure I picked the right initial conditions.

Comment: Just plug it into equation (7) in http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx and apply boundary condition $Q(0)=50$

Comment: Okay I added my work and I got the initial condition and solved for $C$ but I fail to see how I can proceed beyond where I am. I appreciate your time.

Comment: You know how much time do you need to fill the tank, since you add a net of 2 gal/sec, and you need to add 300 gals. So $t=150$. I've edited you question to put $c$ in the last equation. I get a slightly different answer than your book, $400-50/8=393.75$

Comment: Okay that makes perfect sense thank you

Comment: It seems that c the that put down is different it doesnt have 50 squared under a cube root

Comment: That's throwing me off